# KOFAX Capture 10.1 - PDF Generator - Change Path

Tags: kofax

is it possible to change the pdf generator path?

normally the generator create a *.PDF folder in my capturesv/images folder.
i would like to route the PDF documents to a different path.

Normally:

- ..CaptureSV/images/00000BFA/200/1.tif
- ..CaptureSV/images/00000BFA.PDF/59E73606.pdf

Expected

- ..CaptureSV/images/00000BFA/200/1.tif
- ..PDF/00000BFA.PDF/59E73606.pdf

a alternative could be a WFA that change the image path in the batch after scan and change it back after pdf generator.

is there a way to do that?

Comment: You probably already understand this but, this path is only temporary while the batch is in Kofax Capture.  Depending on what kind of export connector you are using, usually you can specify a path there they will end up at the end once you export.  
If this doesn't meet your needs, can you clarify why you need a different PDF path while the batch is still in the system? What drives that need?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path of your PDF output by changing the storage folder indicated in your Export Connector.

To do that, you'll need to select your connector on your **Document class** (not your Batch class). To do so, right click on your Document class and pick "Export connectors", click "Configure" on your installed export connector.
You'll see a panel with three tabs : *Default Storage, Index Storage and Advanced*.

Click on the *Advanced* tab and you'll see [your connector's output paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMnaj.png)

Just change your storage on the PDF output from "Default storage folder" to "Custom storage folder" and pick yourself a fitting path for your PDF output by clicking the "Custom" button which will be enabled.